# Jquery ajax call to webservice on localhost error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services

I have a writen a webservice that returns data in Json format which I've tried and tested and all of which works just fine. I am now busy writing a web client that can consume the service in html (of course) and jquery to handle the actual calls.

This is the snippet of jquery I'm using to do the call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/UserStore/webapi/myresource/4"
    }).then(function(data) {
        alert('id: ' + data.id + ", username: " + data.username + ", password: " + data.password + ", email: " + data.email);
    });
});
```

When this runs I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:8080/UserStore/webapi/myresource/4`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost`' is therefore not allowed access.

Which... is all French to me... and I don't know French.. so there you go.

Comment: Are you doing a crossdomain ajax request? if yes set the proper headers there to access.

Comment: Allow cross domain request server side

Comment: @Relborg then try after removing `http://localhost:8080` and adding the `dataType:'json'`.

Comment: seems like you web api and the ajax call application are on different ports ..is it?

Comment: Yes it's deff on different ports

Comment: then you need to set headers to allow cross domain calls in your web service

Comment: BTW you have a syntax error here `email: " + data,email);` you have a `,` instead of `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you could use the public ip of your machine if the website and the web-service working on the same machine. So access the page over `http://<your-public-ip>/` and for jQuery `url: "http://<your-public-ip>"`.

But this only works if the port is the same, I guess.

If the site and the service are not on the same port, you have to implement CORS on serverside. (If you use Java EE, I could post an example.)

EDIT:

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-property-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type, X-Requested-With</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>X-Test-1, X-Test-2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
        <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> // map this to your Jersey-Servlet-Path
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I'm guessing i have to implement CORS then.. I'm using Jersey

Comment: As this is my first web service I've created I've never heard of CORS.. I guess I have some reading to do then.. again. Thanks!